# Android Deeplink in Mandrill Template

Tags: android, email, android-intent, deep-linking, mandrill

I am trying to put an android deeplink my mobile developer gave me in a mandrill email template:

the deep link he gave me is:

```
intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end
```

What is the proper syntax for embedding this in an template? Ive tried:

```
"intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end"
<a>intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end</a>
<a>"intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the emails you send out will be opened on Android devices only? Those deeplinks will not resolve on other devices.

The specific syntax of links you're trying work on Chrome Version 25+. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

I recommend using http://urx.com/documentation to redirect customers to the best possible place to consume your content. It works provided the link you're sharing has the required meta-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
window.location = 'intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end'
```

or

```
<a href="intent://products/?batch=1#Intent;scheme=productstore;package=com.productmakers.store;end">link text</a>
```

I hope this answers your question!